applying adverbs to nominalized adjectives
I believe it's correct to refer to something that's, say, elegant gesprochen as das elegant gesprochene Ding, which can further be rewritten as das elegante Gesprochene. Easy enough. But what happens if I want to similarly pithily rewrite das darin gesprochene Ding, where the adverb I'm using on the adjective I want to nominalize doesn't have an adjectival form/declensions? In English one can technically treat "the therein said" as a substantive, and I'm wondering if there's a way either to do the same thing in German or to otherwise achieve the same meaning in about the same space.
Also, I'd like to know if I can get away with doing this sort of thing in a poem, where I'd want to sound (very) formal but not awkward; in other words, whether a native speaker would see this as "doing an uncommon (and perhaps interesting) thing with language" or "obviously a non-native-speaker attempting something they shouldn't be attempting."

Just my opinion, but writing poetry in one's native language is difficult enough, at least if result is to be worth reading. Maybe start with something a bit more forgiving, like writing internet discussion board posts in German. That said, I found this example in the DWDS usage database: "Später, als nichts klar war, hob er die Augen ... und sah in Odiles Augen, die das zwischen ihnen Gesprochene erklärteen." Is that close to what you're getting at?

Note that "das elegant Gesprochene" and "das elegante Gesprochene" are both at least theoretically possible, but mean different things. The former is spoken elegantly, but the latter is just something that is spoken, and it is elegant.

An adverb can be applied to a nominalized adjective just as it can be applied to any other adjective:

Das elegant Gesprochene


Das gestern Gesagte

Therefore, there is no reason to turn the adverb into an adjective. Actually, if this is done, it usually causes a subtle change of meaning, as Rakenolli mentioned in his comment.
